# How do you mock urllib.requests.urlopen?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, urllib

I'm making a screen-scraper that collects schedule data from a TV channel website. To do that, I have to fetch the website's raw HTML. I'm trying my hand at unit-testing for the first time and I have some knowledge about mocking, but I'm not too confident about it yet. (If someone could provide some good learning resources on this, I'd be more than grateful.)

The way I'm going about this is I'm trying to return a schedule class that will parse the DOM from the HTML data and strip the schedule data, like so:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_html():
    url = "https://example.com"
    response = urlopen(url)
    dom = response.read()
    return SomeScheduleClass(dom)
```

My point is I have no idea how to test if it actually returns `SomeScheduleClass` as expected. Do I mock the `http.client.HTTPResponse` object I get from the `urlopen`? Do I somehow find a way to mock the `response.read()`? Or do I not have to test this at all and I'm just wasting my time? If so, what should I test here?

On an unrelated note, I'm still very much rusty since everything I know about Python is self-learnt, so if this is incredibly basic and I'm wasting everyone's time, I'd be more than happy to delete this question and forget it ever existed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I revised my previous answer. I hope the new answer is better.

Answer (score -4):

## Short Version

Now we are interested in controlling the expected outcome of `fetch_html()`, that means we have to control the input of the function. This function uses `urllib.request.urlopen()` to get a response from the http server of the domain `example.com`. That url is actually the input of the function. To control it and to make sure we can run the test without having to make any "real" http requests to "example.com", we have to mock `urllib.request.urlopen()`, so that it returns a predefined `response`. One way to do that is to patch urllib.request.urlopen() to return a instance of a class that mocks `Response` by exposing a .read() funciton that return a preloaded HTML.

Here is an implementation using `unittest`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.schedules import SomeScheduleClass
from src.utils import fetch_html

class TestFetchHtml(unittest.TestCase):
    # mocked html content. It can be re-used when testing SomeScheduleClass
    mock_html_content = b"<html>Mock example.com HTML content</html>"

    # class to mock the http response class returned by urlopen
    class MockResponse:
        def read(self):
            return TestFetchHtml.mock_html_content

    # Prepare mocking
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_response = TestFetchHtml.MockResponse()

    def test_fetch_html(self):
        with patch('urllib.request.urlopen', return_value=self.mock_response) as mocked_urlopen:
            # call the function to be tested
            result = fetch_html()
            mocked_urlopen.assert_called_once_with("https://example.com")

            # assert the return value is an object of type SomeScheduleClass
            self.assertIsInstance(result, SomeScheduleClass)

            # some assertions to make sure result contains the expected value
            # it should be extensive since we are not testing SomeScheduleClass here
            # Additional assertions could be added here as needed
```

And here is an implementation using `pytest`.

you will have first to install:

```
pip3 install pytest pytest-mock
```

`pytest-mock` provides the fixture `mocker` that is a thin wrapper of functionalities of `unittest.mock`.

then you can use `pytest`, and `mocker` in the `test_fetch_html()` function as shown below:

```
import pytest
from src.schedules import SomeScheduleClass
from src.utils import fetch_html

@pytest.mark.UNIT
def test_fetch_html(mocker):
    # mocked html content. It can be re-used when testing SomeScheduleClass
    mock_html_content = b"<html>Mock example.com HTML content</html>"
    # class to mock the http response class returned by urlopen
    class MockResponse:
        def read(self):
            return mock_html_content
    mock_response = MockResponse()
    # mock urllib.request.urlopen to return mock_response
    p = mocker.patch('urllib.request.urlopen', return_value=mock_response)
    # call the function to be tested
    r = fetch_html()
    # assert urlopen was called once with url: https://example.com
    p.assert_called_once_with("https://example.com")
    # assert the return value is an object of type SomeScheduleClass
    assert isinstance(r, SomeScheduleClass)
    # some assertions to make sure r contains the exected value
    # it should be be extensive since we are not testing SomeScheduleClass
```

## Long Version

This is a great general question that deserves a general answer. Althgouh Stackoverflow is a great place to get answers, I don't believe an answer here no matter how good would be a substitute for more a more substantial reading, courses and hands-on experience. Nonetheless, I will try to be thorough.

Test automation is great topic in software development, and it is an essential part of SecDevOps, and plays a very important role in modern software development. I personally learned about test automation late in my 30 years+ of software development, and a part of me wishes I have taken up writing tests or test-driven software development earlier, and therefore, I encourage you to proceed on this path and take your test automation skills to the next level.

I will assume that the questions of **What is Test Automation?**, and **Why is test automation important?** are clear to you, and I will proceed to the next questions **What to test?** and **When to test?**:

## What to test?

In your question you write and I quote:

> Blockquote
> My point is I have no idea how to test if it actually returns SomeScheduleClass as expected. Do I mock the http.client.HTTPResponse object I get from the urlopen? Do I somehow find a way to mock the response.read()? Or do I not have to test this at all and I'm just wasting my time? If so, what should I test here?

This is an essential question. Writing tests for your already existing code is "work" and "takes" time and energy, so the why question is not just a philosophical question but it is also an engineering question. There are several approaches and strategies that Quality Assurance managers, or CI/CD pipelines managers or CIOs would implement or prefer. I will try to list some **strategies** that I hope are useful to address the general **What to test?** question, then I will address the question about the snippet of code you shared.

#### Use test driven-development

Test driven development means writing the tests before (or while) you are writing code. This method allows to ensure high test coverage, and also force you to design the code in a way that makes it easy to test.

#### Focus on regression tests

If you are not implementing test-driver development, and you don't have high coverage of your code, then you would want to start with writing a test for everytime you discover a bug in the code. The goal of writing these regression tests is to ensure bugs do not resurface after they get fixed. Also writing regression tests slowly increases code coverage until you reach a point where you can switch to test-driven development. If you are already implementing test-driven development, then adding regression tests will cover cases you did not address in previous tests, and will ensure bugs do not resurface upon code refactoring. In other words, Bug fixing means writing test code that reproduce the bug case, then fixing the bug so that the bug is averted and the test passes.

#### Focus on the most critical part of your code:

Writing tests is time consuming. If you are going to invest this time in writing tests, then invest time in covering the most essential part of the code, or the most difficult part that is potentially buggy. That will allow you to discover/avert runtime bugs, and might also help you redesign the code so that it is more modular and simpler.

#### Write tests for your code

Don't waste your time writing tests for functions of 3rd party packages. Most packages already have tests. Write tests for your code, test all branches of a function, test all functions in a class or module, test all modules. Use a test coverage analysis tool to easily zoom in on code that is not coverage by tests.

#### Focus on Interfaces

When writing code that interfaces with 3rd party services or APIs, then focusing on those interfaces is not a bad idea, because it will allow you to detect any changes in the apis

#### Set a coverage target:

And add a rule such as ensure when code is committed, coverage does not decrease.

#### Security driven tests writing:

With this strategy, the goal is to ensure that all edge cases, stress situation, or any security issue is covered. Here you write tests that are designed to break the system, then adjust the code such as the system does not break, or such as the system fails in an expected and controlled way. Every time a security issue is discovered, addressing the issue means writing a test(s) that reproduce it and fixing the code so that the test(s) passes, which is similar to writing regression tests.

#### Focus on use cases:

Write tests that covers use cases of your code, or that are driven by the end-users of the code/tool. That way you cover the part related to the user-experience. That can accelerate the speed at which features and fixes are delivered to the end-user, by reducing the development/manual-testing iterations of new features or code fixes.

#### What to test in the code snippet:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_html():
    url = "https://example.com"
    response = urlopen(url)
    dom = response.read()
    return SomeScheduleClass(dom)
```

I will start by writing Unit test for fetch_html, the test should ensure that the function returns an instance of type SomeScheduleClass, and that content of that instance is what is expected from parsing some `dom` with the `SomeScheduleClass`. We are not interested in testing `urllib.request.urlopen` because it is not your code. We are not interested in testing SomeScheduleClass constructor in `test_fetch_html()` because it should be tested in the Unit tests of the class `SomeScheduleClass`.

Now we are interested in controlling the expected outcome of `fetch_html()`, that means we have to control the input of the function. This function uses `urllib.request.urlopen()` to get a response from the http server of the domain `example.com`. That url is actually the input of the function. To control it and to make sure we can run the test without having to make any "real" http requests to "example.com", we have to mock `urllib.request.urlopen()`, so that it returns a predefined `response`. One way to do that is to patch urllib.request.urlopen() to return a instance of a class that mocks `Response` by exposing a .read() funciton that return a preloaded HTML.

Here is an implementation using `unittest`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.schedules import SomeScheduleClass
from src.utils import fetch_html

class TestFetchHtml(unittest.TestCase):
    # mocked html content. It can be re-used when testing SomeScheduleClass
    mock_html_content = b"<html>Mock example.com HTML content</html>"

    # class to mock the http response class returned by urlopen
    class MockResponse:
        def read(self):
            return TestFetchHtml.mock_html_content

    # Prepare mocking
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_response = TestFetchHtml.MockResponse()

    def test_fetch_html(self):
        with patch('urllib.request.urlopen', return_value=self.mock_response) as mocked_urlopen:
            # call the function to be tested
            result = fetch_html()
            mocked_urlopen.assert_called_once_with("https://example.com")

            # assert the return value is an object of type SomeScheduleClass
            self.assertIsInstance(result, SomeScheduleClass)

            # some assertions to make sure result contains the expected value
            # it should be extensive since we are not testing SomeScheduleClass here
            # Additional assertions could be added here as needed
```

And here is an implementation using `pytest`.

you will have first to install:

```
pip3 install pytest pytest-mock
```

`pytest-mock` provides the fixture `mocker` that is a thin wrapper of functionalities of `unittest.mock`.

then you can use `pytest`, and `mocker` in the `test_fetch_html()` function as shown below:

```
import pytest
from src.schedules import SomeScheduleClass
from src.utils import fetch_html

@pytest.mark.UNIT
def test_fetch_html(mocker):
    # mocked html content. It can be re-used when testing SomeScheduleClass
    mock_html_content = b"<html>Mock example.com HTML content</html>"
    # class to mock the http response class returned by urlopen
    class MockResponse:
        def read(self):
            return mock_html_content
    mock_response = MockResponse()
    # mock urllib.request.urlopen to return mock_response
    p = mocker.patch('urllib.request.urlopen', return_value=mock_response)
    # call the function to be tested
    r = fetch_html()
    # assert urlopen was called once with url: https://example.com
    p.assert_called_once_with("https://example.com")
    # assert the return value is an object of type SomeScheduleClass
    assert isinstance(r, SomeScheduleClass)
    # some assertions to make sure r contains the exected value
    # it should be be extensive since we are not testing SomeScheduleClass
```

It is evident that this function does not have any error handling and any exception raised will be handled in by the invoking function. So when testing the invoking function, edge cases should be addressed, such as the case that example.com was not reachable, or if example.com returned 4xx or 5xx or something like that.

## When to test?

i.e. when to run the tests, during development, after committing to the branch? on merge requests? on staging? on deployment?
In "The DevOps Handbook" (which I highly recommend), while discussing the "2nd second way, the principles of feedback" the advise is to "Keep pushing quality closer to source" and "to enable optimization for teams downstream". In practicle terms, developers should be able to test their code before committing it (pushing quality closer to source), and any bug in the code should be discovered as soon as possible before it reaches production, the closer the bug is discovered to its source, the better. I would recommend, enabling developers to run all tests before committing code. but that means developers should be able to create production-like environments on their own... there is so much here to discuss.

## Tools of the Trade:

### UnitTest

Python comes with built in facility for testing using unittest https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html.

### PyTest

I personally prefer the pytest https://pytest.org/ framework because of many reasons such as:

- pytest makes organising tests much simpler and much flexible than unittest.
- It also make parameterising tests much simpler.
- It also more economic in terms of lines of code
- and in case you already have tests written for unittest, pytest can still run them.

### Tox

From the tox website https://tox.wiki/en/4.13.0/:
tox is a generic virtual environment management and test command line tool you can use for

- checking your package builds and installs correctly under different environments (such as different Python implementations, versions or installation dependencies),
- running your tests in each of the environments with the test tool of choice,
- acting as a frontend to continuous integration servers, greatly reducing boilerplate and merging CI and shell-based testing.
- it is extendible and already has tons of plugins for mocking or other test related functionality

## Resources:

I am actually working on a book/udemy course for using pytest, but it is not ready yet, until then I would recommend the following resources:

#### Websites

- https://pytest.org/
- https://tox.wiki/en/4.13.0/

#### Courses:

- https://www.udemy.com/course/elegant-automation-frameworks-with-python-and-pytest
- https://www.udemy.com/course/api-testing-python/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHYq1MRoyI0

#### Podcasts:

- https://podcast.pythontest.com/

#### Books:

- The Phoenix Project: https://itrevolution.com/product/the-phoenix-project/
- The Unicorn Project: https://itrevolution.com/product/the-unicorn-project/
- The DevOps Handbook: https://itrevolution.com/product/the-devops-handbook-second-edition/
- Test Driven Python Development: https://www.packtpub.com/en-us/product/test-driven-python-development-9781783987924

Comment: Thanks for the resource! But I'd still like to have my other question asked though. The one about which one to mock. Also, the documentations are a bit hard to parse for beginners like me, so if this isn't asking for too much, if you know any other easier-to-understand resources, please let me know!

Comment: @MavrikLokeeh I will try to elaborate as soon as I have some free time

Comment: OP isn't using `requests` though so I don't see how `requests-mock` would help them here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My answer from 2021 is inadequate and does not address the actual question. Thank you for pointing that out. I will try to rewrite the answer in a satisfactory manner within a week. I am already looking into my old notes on mocking, and testing options.

Comment: I hope the answer is now (after a complete re-write) satisfactory...